# Python:: Sklearn OpenBLAS Error for KMeans

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, openblas

I get the following error when I try to use Kmeans:

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=numClusters, max_iter=100, n_init='auto')

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\PythonVirtualEnv\MLHogwarts\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py:870: FutureWarning: The default value of `n_init` will change from 10 to 'auto' in 1.4. Set the value of `n_init` explicitly to suppress the warning
  warnings.warn(
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OOOOOpOenpBLASOOOeOOOOppOenBOLAOS O: OPOOpOeOpenBLenBLpenBLAOpeOpenBpenBpnpenBLASOpenBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This AS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of  : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
OpS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many penBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
with a larger NUM_THREADS value or set the environment variableOpenBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
wAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This librlibrary penBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many OpenBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
wipary was built to support aenBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
This library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
wOwith a larger NUM_THREADS value or set the environment variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS to
aenBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate too many memory regions.
penBLAS : Program is Terminated. Because you tried to allocate tThis library was built to support a maximum of 50 threads - either rebuild OpenBLAS
with a larger NUM_THREADS value or set the environment variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS to
aith a larger NUM_THREADS value or set the environment variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS to
a sufficiently small number. This error typically occurs when the software that relies on
OpenBLAS calls BLAS functions from many threads in parallel, or when your computer has more
cpu cores than what OpenBLAS was configured to handle.
wenmpnOpmppnrL opL BOppt  5O pipaO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I installed numpy and sklearn using pip install.

I am aware of this thread for similar problem:
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/3321

Per suggestions, I added the following to my code

```
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

However, I still get the same error as above.

I have the following version of numpy and sklearn

```
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.1
numpy==1.24.2
numpydoc==1.5.0
Python 3.9.12
```

can anyone help resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with Tsne in sklearn. Did you solve it ? thanks

Comment: I was able to use MiniBatchKMeans to resolve this issue. It is related to how numpy handles parallelism. If you are on Python 3.6 and beyond, try to revert back to Python 3.6 and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, but it was solved by prescribing what you tried.

```
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
```

Maybe because I have python=3.10

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this, couldn't get rid of those errors even when setting the environment variables in the function before the call to 'fit'.  I finally fixed it by setting the environment variables up before the relevant imports.

```
import os
default_n_threads = 8
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = f"{default_n_threads}"
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = f"{default_n_threads}"
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = f"{default_n_threads}"

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

...